# i am doing the google assistant on a raspberry pi and i keep getting _atomic_exchange_8

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

i keep getting

ImportError: /home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_exchange_8

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should give more details about your system, your Python exact version, context about your problem, what you have already tried, etc.

However I'd try that:

First run:

```
sudo find / -type f -name '*atom*.so*'
```

You should find the lib you are looking for on the system, let's say it is:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0
```

Now, just add `LD_PRELOAD` variable definition before running your python3 program:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 your-command
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I get the _atomic_exchange_8 is not a command

Comment: export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 your-command
bash: your-command: comando non trovato

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).